# How to customize my launch screen xib for a specific device (iPhone X)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have a launch screen xib, that basically contains a `UIView` (parent) and within it a `UIImageView` (child).

So **ONLY when the app is running on an iPhone X**, I want to totally hide the `UIImageView` (child) and then change the background color of the `UIView` (parent).

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Simple answer; you can’t. There is no specific trait for the iPhone X

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11 you can't perform any logical operation of your own, even though you cant even use a subclass of an UIView or something. For this i would suggest you to use Static launch images, the size for these launch images are mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/)

Comment: If the image is in full screen mode you can use Image assets catalogue.